# How to JPA within a JAR?

Tags: java, jpa, jar, entitymanager

Is it possible to use JPA within plain Java applications resulting in JAR files run locally? I often used the `EntityManager` and `@Entity` annotations for web application creation resulting in WAR files and configured the persistence unit for use over databases configured and managed within the Wildfly server. I find this functionality quite convenient and would like to use it outside of an application server environment. Are there working examples to that? Or maybe similar approaches?

Comment: Neither `EntityManager` or `@Entity` are web application or application server specific, you just need to wire them differently depending on your environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try SpringBoot using JPA, here is a definitive guide by Spring: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Using springboot, you can get a single jar file with it's dependencies within it.